# Redis connections not being released after Celery task is complete

Tags: python, heroku, redis, celery, connection-pooling

I'm using Redis for two things: 1) As the Celery backend and 2) As a lock holder for my Celery task

Here's an example of the code I'm running:

```
def get_redis():
    url = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL")

    if url:
        r = redis.from_url(url)  # use secure for heroku
    else:
        r = redis.Redis()  # use unauthed connection locally

    return r

@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=10)
def test_delay_task(self, task_id):
    ''' Each task with try to grab a lock and once it does, will sleep 5 seconds, then
    print and exit.
    '''
    have_lock = False
    r = get_redis()
    lock = r.lock('mws_api')
    try:
        have_lock = lock.acquire(blocking=False)
        if have_lock:
            logger.warning("{} Lock Acquired".format(task_id))
            time.sleep(5)
            logger.warning('Test Task {} successful!'.format(task_id))
        else:
            logger.warning("{} Lock In Use, Retrying".format(task_id))
            self.request.retries = 1
            self.retry(countdown=5 * random.uniform(0.8, 1.2))

    finally:
        if have_lock:
            lock.release()

        # We'll come back to this code, but it partially works
        # c = r.info()['connected_clients']
        # print("Disconnecting Redis | Connections: {}".format(c))
        # r.connection_pool.disconnect()


@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=10)
def test_parallel_tasks(self):
    ''' Runs 10 consecutive tasks, each which will try to grab a lock and run. '''
    for i in range(5):
        test_delay_task.delay(i)
```

When I run this, I get a large spike in connections to Redis. I'm measuring this with this code:

```
def get_connected_clients():
    try:
        connections = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(.25)
            c = get_redis().info()['connected_clients']
            # c = redis.Redis().info()['connected_clients']
            if c != connections:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                print("{} | Active Connections: {}".format(now, c))
                connections = c
            else:
                continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting Down")
```

The results are this:

```
Celery Starts
2017-11-04 01:29:51.463512 | Active Connections: 7
2017-11-04 01:29:52.477220 | Active Connections: 12


Run Task
2017-11-04 01:30:18.755118 | Active Connections: 33
2017-11-04 01:30:23.847573 | Active Connections: 34
2017-11-04 01:30:24.101263 | Active Connections: 39
2017-11-04 01:30:24.610450 | Active Connections: 40
2017-11-04 01:30:28.944949 | Active Connections: 41
2017-11-04 01:30:30.208845 | Active Connections: 43
2017-11-04 01:30:33.780812 | Active Connections: 42
2017-11-04 01:30:34.548651 | Active Connections: 43
2017-11-04 01:30:34.804526 | Active Connections: 44
2017-11-04 01:30:35.058731 | Active Connections: 47
2017-11-04 01:30:39.626745 | Active Connections: 48
2017-11-04 01:30:40.648594 | Active Connections: 49
Task Complete

Wait

Kill Celery
2017-11-04 01:31:57.766001 | Active Connections: 45
2017-11-04 01:31:58.786042 | Active Connections: 5
2017-11-04 01:31:59.291814 | Active Connections: 3
```

These connections never go away, near as I can tell, unless I close Celery and restart it. Running the task again increases the number of open connections, it never decreases until I close Celery. After 3 runs, the active connection count is up to 77.

---

If I add in the commented code in my task above, it seems to help, but the total connections still seem to high to me. Running multiple times now looks like this:

```
Started with Disconnect Code Uncommented
2017-11-04 01:37:44.773113 | Active Connections: 29
2017-11-04 01:37:54.689032 | Active Connections: 33
2017-11-04 01:37:59.789031 | Active Connections: 32
2017-11-04 01:38:01.057219 | Active Connections: 33
2017-11-04 01:38:02.330613 | Active Connections: 36
2017-11-04 01:38:06.139188 | Active Connections: 35
2017-11-04 01:38:07.917854 | Active Connections: 36
2017-11-04 01:38:13.016428 | Active Connections: 35
2017-11-04 01:39:11.848758 | Active Connections: 36
Second Run
2017-11-04 01:39:18.224475 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:39:22.043765 | Active Connections: 37
2017-11-04 01:39:23.061727 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:39:38.106320 | Active Connections: 37
Third Run
2017-11-04 01:40:49.623050 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:40:54.480170 | Active Connections: 37
2017-11-04 01:40:55.501791 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:41:00.330222 | Active Connections: 37
2017-11-04 01:41:03.643833 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:41:08.735973 | Active Connections: 37
2017-11-04 01:41:10.257756 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:41:15.348323 | Active Connections: 37
2017-11-04 01:41:17.137816 | Active Connections: 38
2017-11-04 01:41:22.241020 | Active Connections: 37
```

---

Ok, so all that said, my question is: why are my connections not closing, and how to I fix that? I'm going to need to run similar code but for 100+ parallel tasks, not just the 5 I'm using here for my example.

Comment: what Redis binding are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by Redis binding? (You can assume from my lack of knowledge that I'm using whatever the default is). I'm using the redis==2.10.5 library.

Comment: I see you're using redis-py, about binding, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding).

Comment: then how many celery worker processes are there?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663288/how-do-i-properly-use-connection-pools-in-redis. You are not using a connection pool and then created redis connection again and again to event fetch the connected clients info. You should not use `get_redis().info()['connected_clients']`. Rather create the object outside loop `r = get_redis()` and then inside loop use `r.info()['connected_clients']`

Comment: @TarunLalwani oh yeah, you are definitely right on that. I fixed that and it didn't change anything noticeable with the connection counts.

Comment: @georgexsh I'm just runnning `celery -A config -l info worker` with no other arguments, so whatever that translates into. I was reading the docs and can't find anywhere saying if that creates multiple workers.

Comment: Doesn't the `redis.connection_pool.disconnect()` work? Looking at the library source, this should disconnect all the connections.

Comment: what's your celery and redis version? And how do you launch the tasks?

Comment: @BorisSerebrov it definitely closes some of them, as you can see in the question though, there are still abut 28 open connections left after running this task. I suspect it has something to do with getting the Lock, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ffeast, celery==4.0.2, Redis server v=4.0.1. I start the task with a .delay() call from terminal.

Comment: @Jeff have you checked my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code that appears to be working.
At least I can't reproduce the problem unlike the original one.
Notice `app.conf.broker_pool_limit = 0` and `connection_pool.disconnect`.
Here's what [broker_pool_limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-pool-limit) does:

> The maximum number of connections that can be open in the connection
>   pool. If set to None or 0 the connection pool will be disabled and connections will be established and closed for every use.

```
import os
import time
import random
import datetime
import logging
import redis

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from celery import Celery
from celery.contrib import rdb
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost')

app.conf.broker_pool_limit = 0

def get_redis():
    url = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL")

    if url:
        r = redis.from_url(url)  # use secure for heroku
    else:
        r = redis.Redis()  # use unauthed connection locally

    return r

@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=10)
def test_delay_task(self, task_id):
    ''' Each task with try to grab a lock and once it does, will sleep 5 seconds, then
    print and exit.
    '''
    have_lock = False
    redis_cli = get_redis()
    lock = redis_cli.lock('mws_api')
    try:
        have_lock = lock.acquire(blocking=False)
        if have_lock:
            logger.warning("{} Lock Acquired".format(task_id))
            time.sleep(5)
            logger.warning('Test Task {} successful!'.format(task_id))
        else:
            logger.warning("{} Lock In Use, Retrying".format(task_id))
            self.request.retries = 1
            self.retry(countdown=5 * random.uniform(0.8, 1.2))
    finally:
        if have_lock:
            lock.release()
        redis_cli.connection_pool.disconnect()

        # We'll come back to this code, but it partially works
        # c = r.info()['connected_clients']
        # print("Disconnecting Redis | Connections: {}".format(c))
        # r.connection_pool.disconnect()


@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=10)
def test_parallel_tasks(self):
    ''' Runs 10 consecutive tasks, each which will try to grab a lock and run. '''
    for i in range(5):
        test_delay_task.delay(i)


def get_connected_clients():
    try:
        connections = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(.25)
            c = get_redis().info()['connected_clients']
            # c = redis.Redis().info()['connected_clients']
            if c != connections:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                print("{} | Active Connections: {}".format(now, c))
                connections = c
            else:
                continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting Down")
```

When this code is run every worker holds only a single connection after  every worker has had a chance to handle a request + a bunch of connections held by the master celery process.

**Connections math**

For this script the master `celery` process needs **8** connections, `ipython` shell takes **4** connections after some tasks has been queried, and **1** connection per `celery` worker once a task has been processed by the worker. So the initial spike is caused by the `celery` master that needs so many connections. Without `broker_pool_limit` set it initially needs **10** connections

Comment: This decreased the number of connections needed. It maxes out around 20 connections now, which fits your math there. Thanks for helping me understand this!

Comment: Thanks ffeast! How did you do the "Connections Math"? Are there docs/code somewhere that detail how many connections `celery` and `ipython` need?

Comment: Does it possible to share connections between celery preforked work process when it is processing tasks? redis.py(>=3.2) is process safe, it might be possible theoretically?  If every preforked process holds a connection, the max concurrency of celery cluster is limited by the max connections of redis, however celery is not support redis cluster yet, and redis connection becomes a bottleneck.