# What is the recommended way to instantiate and pass around a redis client with FastAPI

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI with Redis. My app looks something like this

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import redis

# Instantiate redis client
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)

# Instantiate fastapi app
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/foo/")
async def foo():
    x = r.get("foo")
    return {"message": x}

@app.get("/bar/")
async def bar():
    x = r.get("bar")
    return {"message": x}
```

**Is it bad practice to create `r` as a module-scoped variable like this? If so what are the drawbacks?**

In Tiangolo's tutorial on setting up a [SQL database connection](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency) he uses a dependency, which I guess in my case would look something like this

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
import redis

# Instantiate fastapi app
app = FastAPI()

# Dependency
def get_redis():
    return redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)

@app.get("/foo/")
async def foo(r = Depends(get_redis)):
    x = r.get("foo")
    return {"message": x}

@app.get("/bar/")
async def bar(r = Depends(get_redis)):
    x = r.get("bar")
    return {"message": x}
```

I'm a bit confused as to which of these methods (or something else) would be preferred and why.

Comment: It depends (as always). Your first example reuses the same client for all your endpoints (and, blocks the event loop while using that client because you use it in async endpoints but that is another matter). In the second example, you get a new instance for each request. But actually you also get a new connection pool with each request. My recommendation would be to make a global connection pool and use dependency injection to get a connection from that pool (`redis.Redis(connection_pool=redis_pool)`). That way, you don't make a new connection pool for each request.

Comment: @JarroVGIT thanks, I *think* this makes sense, after reading [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663288/how-do-i-properly-use-connection-pools-in-redis). Any chance you could provide a minimal example as a solution? (I'd be happy to accept it.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Depends` will evaluate every time your function got a request, so your second example will create a new connection for each request. As @JarroVGIT said, we can use connection pooling to maintain the connection from FastAPI to Redis and reduce open-closing connection costs.

Usually, I create a different file to define the connection. Let's say we have `config/db.py`:

```py
import redis

def create_redis():
  return redis.ConnectionPool(
    host='localhost', 
    port=6379, 
    db=0, 
    decode_responses=True
  )

pool = create_redis()
```

Then in the `main.py`

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
import redis

from config.db import pool

app = FastAPI()

def get_redis():
  # Here, we re-use our connection pool
  # not creating a new one
  return redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, cache = Depends(get_redis)):
  status = cache.get(item_id)
  return {"item_name": status}


@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
def update_item(item_id: int, cache = Depends(get_redis)):
  cache.set(item_id, "available")
  return {"status": "available", "item_id": item_id}
```

Usually, I also split the dependencies file like [the doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/) so we can call it from our routing module, but for simplicity, I will leave it like this.

You can check [this repo](https://github.com/tegarimansyah/snippet/tree/main/python-fastapi/redis-connection) to experiment by yourself. It has more comprehensive code and I have already created several scenarios that might help you understand the difference. And it will also cover how your first example may block other endpoints.

Comment: Should aioredis (asyncio redis client)be used with async? https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @starking yes, if we run it in an async function. Not sure if we run it in normal (non async) function.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, every time your creating new redis instance and one time it reach max connection limit. If you put code like this that much more clean and re-usable,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import redis

class AppAPI(FastAPI):
    def __init__(self):
        self.redis_client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)

    @app.get("/foo/")
    async def foo():
        x = self.redis_client.get("foo")
        return {"message": x}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/redis/redis-py#connection-pools. You can define the pool at module level and import it wherever needed. All Redis connection will be created out of the pool.

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```